# How do I get a separator with a variable inside the URL in Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.8 to develop a project. I have a page which contains a button, clicking on it will redirect you to a registration page. This button is located in multiple pages, so, when the button is clicked, I want the name of the page from which it was clicked to be shown in the URL.

For Example, take this Youtube link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

The /watch?v=dQ part, I want to have that in my URL, where "watch" would be the current page's name, and v would contain the name/id of the previous page. I have posted the button and the routes below.

Let me know if something else is required.

```
<a href="{{ url ('demo' )}}" class="set-btn btn3">Request a Demo</a>

Route::get('demo','Controller@dropdown_data');

Route::POST('demo','Controller@submit');
```

The get route calls a function to retrieve data for dropdown fields from a database.
The post route calls the function for submission of the details.

Answer (score 0):

With the `url()` helper it is not possible to add URL query parameters. However, when you add a name to the route, you can use the `route()` helper like this on your pages:

```
<a href="{{ url ('demo', ['prev' => 'nameOfCurrentPage')}}" class="set-btn btn3">
    Request a Demo
</a>
```

And like this as your route definition:

```
Route::get('demo','Controller@dropdown_data')->name('demo');
```

Comment: do i need to make any changes in the function also? where it returns the view? I tried this, but this just shows /demo/nameOfCurrentPage in the url and gives an error that the page cannot be found